# Prolog: take a list of two elements, return true if and only if the first element is same as second

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I'm a newbie prolog programmer, and for an assignment, I have to have a basic program that succeeds if and only if list X is a list of two elements, with the first as the same as the second.

From my view of prolog, programs seem to be pretty small, so I typed this in:

```
firstPair(x,x).
```

When I run it under swipl, I get this as output:

```
Syntax error: Operator expected
```

Is there something more that needs to be done?  I thought that if I executed this with say, firstPair(1,2). this would be all it would need to know that it is false.

Comment: From your description it is not clear where the error message comes from: At least the program you show is valid syntax.

Comment: I think you misunderstood your assignment: you're required to write a firstPair(X) (note the *single* argument). Then what 'shape' X is required to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lowercase `x` is not a variable, it's an *atom*. Make `x` uppercase to fix the problem:

```
firstPair(X,X).
```

Second, you do not type this into the interpreter. Rather, you write it into a file `firstPair.pl`, and then read that file into Prolog.

At the command prompt, type this:

```
['firstPair.pl'].
```

Press enter. Now you can use your `firstPair/2` rule.

Finally, since the assignment talks about lists, I think the instructor wanted you to write `firstPair/1`, not `firstPair/2`:

```
firstPair([X,X]).
```

Comment: @false It looks like it was the problem after all :)

Comment: @user1768884: if you (like me) prefer less cluttered syntax, note that also ?- [firstPair]. will works.

Answer (score 0):

Your program/fact

```
firstPair(X,X).
```

will succeed if the two arguments given it can be *unified*, whether they are lists, atoms, variables, etc. To meet your specification, a

> program that succeeds if and only if list X is a list of two elements,
>   with the first as the same as the second.

You need something like this:

```
list_of_two_elements( [X,X] ).
```

This will succeed if passed a single *term* that is (or can be unified with) a list of two elements that are, or can be made through unification, identical. For instance, all of the following will succeed:

- `list_of_two_elements( X ).`

  on success, the variable `X` will be unified with a list of two elements containing the same unbound variable, something like `[V1,V1]`.
- `list_of_two_elements( [1,1] ).`
- `list_of-two_elements( [1,X] ).` (on success, `X` here will have been unified with the integer `1`.)